# python : Assign or updating parameter in List Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am new to python and i am using python `2.7`.
I want to create script which is  **change the case of each letter in string**.
if i Pass **"ABcdE"** script will give output **"abCDe"**.
There are many ways but i want to use [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for this task.

I have used following code:

```
str = 'abcDE';
str1 = [x for x in str if ord(x)>=97 and ord(x)<=122 x-32 elif   ord(x)>=65 and ord(x)<=90 x+32];
```

this is giving me **`Invalid syntax` error**.
I am not understanding what is error.
I have tried another version also:
Please look at screenshot attached.[image]

When you look last try. when i removed updating varible code it runs successful.
My question is why variable modification is not working in Comprehensions?

Comment: There is no `elif` option for list comprehensions, no.

Comment: Have your tried with x-32 enclosed in parentheses, like so x=(x-32)?

Comment: Note that your console output is **text**. Please copy and paste that text here, a screenshot is not searchable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a conditional expression; you are using *filtering* instead, and a filter can't alter what is produced, only limit what elements are considered.

The left-hand side expression should be altered, so the part that produces the value for each element in the iteration:

```
[x.upper() if 122 >= ord(x) >= 97 else x.lower()
 for x in yourstring]
```

The above processes all letters in `yourstring` (I renamed it to avoid using the built-in name `str`), and for each such letter (in `x`), either use the uppercase version if it is a lowercase letter, otherwise use the lowercase version.

Demo:

```
>>> yourstring = 'abcDE'
>>> [x.upper() if 122 >= ord(x) >= 97 else x.lower() for x in yourstring]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'd', 'e']
```

If you want a new string, use `''.join()`:

```
''.join([x.upper() if 122 >= ord(x) >= 97 else x.lower()
         for x in yourstring])
```

*Or* you could just use the built-in [`str.swapcase()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) to do the same job.

Comment: My main question shall we can modify or update variable in Comprehensions?

Comment: @VishalPatel you can't assign to `x`, no. And you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
str1 = [x.lower() if x.isupper() else x.upper() for x in str]
```